# Developer story has inconsistent job duration calculation

Tags: bug, developer-story

I'm editing a Jan 2017-Mar 2017 job experience entry. Based on the formula used elsewhere to calculate job creation, I would expect this to be marked as 3 months; however, it's instead marked as 2:

[image: Jan 2017-Mar 2017 displays as 2 months]

But if I add one more month, changing the end date to April, it jumps to 4 months:
[image: Jan 2017-Apr 2017 displays as 4 months]

This makes it impossible to hold a position for 3 months starting in January 2017. But at other start times, it is possible to hold a position for 3 months.

Comment: What, you mean not all months have 30 days?

Comment: @serakfalcon yeah, sounds precisely like `months = 1 + (lastDay - firstDay) div 30`. Calculations: `lastDay - firstDay` gives 59 days for 1/1 -- 3/1 and 90 days for 1/1 -- 4/1

Comment: If only there were DateTime libraries that would make such calculations easier...

Comment: @Tschallacka Clearly, there is a function to calculate this time period and someone did it the easy way. The solution is to fix the function or use the logic from the DateTime library which does this specific calculation. Not import the entire library.

Comment: usually most languages have standard libraries to take care of this @PrajeethEmanuel no need to import anything. Also those libraries help with pesky things as leap years, leap seconds and other crazy date and time idiosyncrasies that exist.

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post, since the Developer Story feature no longer exists.