# Incorrect length of employment

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

In my developer story profile I have a where I worked for 3 months from January 2018 to March 2018. When I enter these dates it shows as 2 month. Using April 2018 as the end date gives me 4 months.

[image: Position Jan 2018 -> Mar 2018 (2 months)]
[image: Position Jan 2018 -> Apr 2018 (4 months)]

I have no idea which of the two settings should be the correct one for three months.

Comment: Math is hard...

Comment: My intuition tells me that the range should be inclusive, i.e. Jan - Mar -> 3 months. But what do I know :S

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Developer story has inconsistent job duration calculation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366445/developer-story-has-inconsistent-job-duration-calculation)

Comment: Yup! I somehow didn't find that question when I opened mine.